# Trying to get tags key inside a function but displaying as ""

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to get the `tags` of the corresponding box from blog posts during on click. But while console log the print tags, it is displaying as "" inside `randomizedHex()`. The tags is hidden in front end. Could someone please help ?

demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-glade-lsf46?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [blogArticles, setBlogArticles] = useState([]);
  const [showColor, setShowColor] = useState("");
  const [findTag, setFindTag] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setBlogArticles(items);
  }, []);

  const randomizedHex = (blogArticles) => {
    setFindTag(blogArticles.tags);
    console.log("Print tag:", findTag);
    const randomColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    setShowColor(randomColor);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="row">
        {blogArticles.map(
          ({
            sys: { id, createdAt },
            fields: { title, images, description, shortDescription, tags }
          }) => (
            <div key={id} className="column">
              <article
                onClick={() => {
                  randomizedHex(blogArticles);
                }}
                key={id}
                className="blogmaintile"
              >
                <img
                  className="blogImage"
                  key={images}
                  src={images}
                  alt="myimg"
                ></img>
                <div className="blogtitle">
                  <span key={title}>{title}</span>
                </div>
                <section>
                  <p className="blogdescription" key={shortDescription}>
                    {shortDescription}
                  </p>
                </section>
                <section>
                  <p className="blogdescription" key={description}>
                    {description}
                  </p>
                </section>

                <section>
                  <p style={{ display: "none" }} className="tag" key={tags}>
                    {tags}
                  </p>
                </section>

                <section className="col2">
                  <a href="https://google.com">
                    Read more {">"}
                    {">"}
                  </a>
                </section>
              </article>
            </div>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is the issue here: `setFindTag(blogArticles.tags); console.log("Print tag:", findTag);` where you are trying to log `findTag` after updating it? React state updates are asynchronous so the console log will only ever log the `findTag` value from the *current* render cycle, not the one enqueued for the *next* render cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `tags` destructured from `blogArticle.fields` to `randomizedHex`.

```
{blogArticles.map(
  ({
    sys: { id, createdAt },
    fields: { title, images, description, shortDescription, tags } // <-- tags
  }) => (
    <div key={id} className="column">
      <article
        onClick={() => {
          randomizedHex(tags); // <-- pass tags
        }}
        key={id}
        className="blogmaintile"
      >
        ...
      </article>
    </div>
  )
)}
```

Convert `randomizedHex` to consume the passed tags versus the *entire* `blogArticles` array.

```
const randomizedHex = (tags) => {
  setFindTag(tags);
  console.log("Print tag:", tags);
  const randomColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  setShowColor(randomColor);
};
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. This is working. Can I ask you one question, how does react identify which box tags should be passed during on click ?

Comment: @soccerway I'm not really sure what you mean by box tags, but you are presumably mapping over the data elements, so when you are looking at any specific element you have access to a specific element object's properties. Remember, the map callback is a function, so everything in the function is closed over in *that* specific instance of the callback.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying that.... box tags >> I mean tags related each blog element